# SQL Server 2008 R2 tde stop encryption process

Tags: sql, sql-server, encryption, sql-server-2008-r2, tde

I have a rather larger database I will be encrypting using TDE. I have a defined window to complete the encryption. I need a way to stop the encryption process if the time window is exceeded.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft says it is not possible to stop the TDE encryption once it has been started because it creates an exclusive lock on the database.